# What does "per protocol" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning

It's a quote from the TV drama *Manifest*. Here are the lines:

> -**Per protocol**, climbing to penetration altitude.
>   -**Per protocol**, adjusting flight path to storm center.

The drama is about a bunch of passengers and crew of a commercial airliner who suddenly reappear after being presumed dead for over five years.

The plane captain as the speaker of this line is trying to fly up to the sky and looking for some dark lightning to prove his own theory. What confused me is the meaning of **per protocol**. It seems like a regular term of airplane.

Comment: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/370/what-is-the-best-altitude-to-penetrate-a-thunderstorm

Answer (score 1):

Taking into account that

**[protocol](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/protocol)**

> The accepted or established code of procedure or behaviour in any group, organization, or situation.

and that

**[per](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/per)**

> by means of

we can infer that **per protocol** means that the captain **is using the established protocol**, he is following the steps clearly defined in such protocol, the set of mandatory steps that he must execute on facing an specific situation, an emergency. He declares aloud each step, that he's always following the rules, because what he says is being recorded in the **black box** of the plane. In case of accident these records will help to determine the causes, what went wrong.

@Tᴚoɯɐuo suggested that **per protocol** can be paraphrased as **according to / in accord with protocol**.

Comment: +1 for the explanation, but **per protocol** isn't a truncated form of "as per protocol"; rather "as per protocol" is just a variant.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Then in this case, "per" means just "by means of", isn't it?

Comment: I would paraphrase it as "according to" or "in accord with".